# Prevent accepting merge requests on sonar issues

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab with SonarQube executed by Jenkins. I want prevent merge requests from being accepted if SonarQube has reported any issues.

Any ideas for Gitlab CE or EE?

Comment: How are you runnig the SonarQube?

Comment: SonarQube will be triggered by Jenkins

Comment: Okay, in that case I'll assume Gitlab triggers Jenkins and Jenkins triggers SonarQube

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab CI offers two ways to prevent merge requests, if build fails or if there is unresolved discussion.
To start please configure a Jenkins plugin following [this tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html#jenkins-ci-service).
Now that you have the gitlab-jenkins-ci integration and gitlab trigerrs the jenkins build you have to enable `Only allow merge requests to be merged if the build succeeds` in the project settings in gitlab and either install [SonarQube build breaker plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) or use the [rest api](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/sonarqube-build-breaker).

The method not involving build breaking would be to use [gitlab SonarQube plugin](https://gitlab.talanlabs.com/gabriel-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin) however currently it does not support making comments on merge requests so you'd have to either modify the plugin or make a workaround using the gitlab api.

Comment: I am already doing it like that. Jenkins suceeds when maven builds and tests were successful. Sonarqube results will not be considered.

Comment: @NoobieNoob So the real question is how to fail a Jenkins build when SonarQube results are negative?

Comment: Well no, it would be better to separate the Jenkins and Sonarqube results. Jenkins may build the project successfully but the merge should be blocked because Sonarqube has found any issues.

Comment: @NoobieNoob As far as I'm aware there is no existing solution that could do that.