# Is it possible to close merge request automatically in Gitlab if sonarQube reports issues in code

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab, git-merge, sonarqube-scan

I am using Gitlab 'Merge Request events' webhook to start sonar scanner in Jenkins job, once the scan is complete, scan results are posted in Gitlab against that merge request.

Is it possible to close that merge request automatically if there are blocker issues reported by sonar scan?

[image]

Comment: You can always use the Gitlab API to close MR.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of a Sonar plugin calling GitLab API with [`gabriel-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin`](https://gitlab.talanlabs.com/gabriel-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin) (also [visible on GitHub](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin)). But, [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637598/6309), it would not support merge-request API call for now.

The other approach is through the [JENKINS GitLab Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin), to trigger Jenkins builds when code is pushed or a merge request is created. With that plugin, stopped buildings close merge requests. Combine it with [SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker).